# How to realize the following logic in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My initial dataframe looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'document':['abc','abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz','xyz','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','stackover','stackover','stackover','stackover','stackover'],
        'version':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7],
        'status': [100,100,100,16,200,200,11,11,11,11,15,15,11,15,15,15,10,10,100,15,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

And now I want to add the column 'traffic light'. The conditional formatting of the cells is only for better visualization:

[image]

the color of the traffic light comes about as follows:

'status' 100 or 200: This means that the document has been released.

All other 'status' (e.g. 16 or 10): not released

**green:** the highest document version has to be value 'green'

**red:** there is a higher version that is released (status 100 or 200).

**yellow:** there is a higher version that is not released (NOT status 100 or 200).

Can this be implemented directly with the pandas functions or do i need numpy for this? probably the best thing to do is to build in the logic for yellow and red first and then just set the highest version green or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

#get maximum version for each document: green
green = df["version"].eq(df.groupby("document")["version"].transform("max"))

#get maximum version for each document with released status: red
red = df["version"].lt(df["document"].map(df[df["status"].isin([100,200])].groupby("document")["version"].max()))

df["traffic light"] = np.select([green, red], ["green", "red"], "yellow")

>>> df
     document  version  status traffic light
0         abc        1     100           red
1         abc        2     100           red
2         abc        3     100        yellow
3         abc        4      16         green
4         xyz        1     200           red
5         xyz        2     200        yellow
6         xyz        3      11         green
7        test        1      11        yellow
8        test        2      11        yellow
9        test        3      11        yellow
10       test        4      15        yellow
11       test        5      15        yellow
12       test        6      11        yellow
13       test        7      15        yellow
14       test        8      15        yellow
15       test        9      15         green
16  stackover        3      10           red
17  stackover        4      10           red
18  stackover        5     100        yellow
19  stackover        6      15        yellow
20  stackover        7      10         green
```

Comment: Okay that is pandas pro level. Thanks! I

Comment: nice one, you were faster on this one (almost same logic!) ;)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
# make group
g = df.assign(released=df['status'].isin([100,200])).groupby('document')

# get green values
green = df['version'].eq(g['version'].transform('max'))

# get next release
next_released = g['released'].apply(lambda s: s[::-1].cummax().shift(1, fill_value=False)[::-1])

# select values
import numpy as np
df['traffic light'] = np.select([green, next_released], ['green', 'red'], 'yellow')
```

output:

```
     document  version  status traffic light
0         abc        1     100           red
1         abc        2     100           red
2         abc        3     100        yellow
3         abc        4      16         green
4         xyz        1     200           red
5         xyz        2     200        yellow
6         xyz        3      11         green
7        test        1      11        yellow
8        test        2      11        yellow
9        test        3      11        yellow
10       test        4      15        yellow
11       test        5      15        yellow
12       test        6      11        yellow
13       test        7      15        yellow
14       test        8      15        yellow
15       test        9      15         green
16  stackover        3      10           red
17  stackover        4      10           red
18  stackover        5     100        yellow
19  stackover        6      15        yellow
20  stackover        7      10         green
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some step by step solution that adds 2 columns :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

data = {'document':['abc','abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz','xyz','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','stackover','stackover','stackover','stackover','stackover'],
        'version':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7],
        'status': [100,100,100,16,200,200,11,11,11,11,15,15,11,15,15,15,10,10,100,15,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['max version'] = df.groupby('document')['version'].transform('max')
df['max release version'] = df.loc[df["status"]>=100].groupby(['document'])['version'].transform('max')
df['max release version'] = df.groupby('document')['max release version'].transform('max')

df['traffic light'] = numpy.where( df['version']==df['max version'], 'green',
                      numpy.where( (df['max release version'].isnull())
                                  | ((df['max release version']==df['version'])&(df['version']!=df['max version'])), 'yellow',
                      numpy.where( df['version']!=df['max release version'], 'red',
                                 numpy.nan)))
df
```

You can drop the columns :

```
df.drop(['max version','max release version'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
```